# Alfresco 5.0.a - Can't send invitation email but can send the test SMTP mail

Tags: alfresco-share

I tried to follow the setting guide on wiki to set the mail configuration is as below:

```
### E-mail site invitation setting ###
notification.email.siteinvite=true

# Outbound email configuration
mail.host=mail.mydomain.com
mail.port=25
mail.username=none-reply@mydomain.com
mail.password=mypassword
mail.protocol=smtp
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.from.default=none-reply@mydomain.com
mail.smtp.timeout=30000
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
mail.smtp.debug=false

mail.testmessage.send=true
mail.testmessage.to=dong.pt@mydomain.com
mail.testmessage.subject=Outbound SMTP
mail.testmessage.text=The Outbound SMTP email subsystem is working.

email.inbound.enabled=false

imap.server.enabled=false
```

I can receive the testing email when server is starting up to dong.pt@mydomain.com but I can't receive the invitation message when I try to invite to the same email address. The error log is as below:

```
2014-08-17 05:19:54,152  ERROR [action.executer.MailActionExecuter] [http-bio-8085-exec-1] Failed to send email to dong.pt@mydomain.com
 org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 5.7.1 <admin@alfresco.com>... Permission denied
;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 5.7.1 <admin@alfresco.com>... Permission denied
; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 5.7.1 <admin@alfresco.com>... Permission denied
;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 5.7.1 <admin@alfresco.com>... Permission denied

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2202)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1693)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1194)
    at org.alfresco.repo.mail.AlfrescoJavaMailSender$PooledTransportWrapper.sendMessage(AlfrescoJavaMailSender.java:165)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:416)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:336)
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.MailActionExecuter.sendEmail(MailActionExecuter.java:953)
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.MailActionExecuter.executeImpl(MailActionExecuter.java:493)
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.ActionExecuterAbstractBase.execute(ActionExecuterAbstractBase.java:265)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:72)

    ... <there are tons of log> more
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Eehum does the mail dong.pt@mydomain.com exist? I'm not sure why the authentication issues are coming from. But in the code it just fails to send an email.

Comment: Yes, it exist. And I even can send the test email to it from this application. You might see this configuration in mail.testmessage.* prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue on Alfresco 5.2 community, email sending was possible, but when a user was added to a site no invitation mail was send. 
(and the paramter notification.email.siteinvite is set to true)

First make sure the rights of 
Data Dictionary\Email Templates\invite 
are correct.

Then the solution for us was to recreate the ftl (template) files with the correct documents. (I took the correct ftl files from a fresh installed Alfresco instance)

Succes